# Symfony environments and debug bar

Tags: php, symfony, wamp, environments

I am new to Symfony. Been doing some tests (Symfony 2.0.13 with php5.3.8 in WAMP2.2) and reading [the](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#configuration) [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) but I am kind of  confused with environments.

When I go to `LOCALHOST/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/Foo` (app_dev means development environment, right?) I can see the web debug toolbar and clicking in the profiler info, in the "project configuration" tab, I can see:
*Environment    dev*

Now I go to `LOCALHOST/Symfony/web/app.php/demo/hello/Foo` and in the web debug toolbar (BTW, why I am seeing this toolbar now? Ain't this a production environment? Are my users supposed to see this bar by default?) I also see, in the "project configuration" tab:
*Environment    dev*

It seems that this "demo" Bundle is somehow associated with "dev", no matter what the URL is app_dev.php or app.php??

Moreover, I did some more tests: my local IP is 192.168.153.1.

When I try to access:

```
http://192.168.153.1/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/Foo
```

it says "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information." So, ok, if I edited the lines in app_dev.php and added my (external) IP, I could access.

BUT, when I connect to

```
http://192.168.153.1/Symfony/web/app.php/demo/hello/Foo
```

IT SAYS THE SAME! So it seems that my app.php is not being executed, and app_dev.php is being executed no matter what I type in the URL.

This is really confusing! I checked my htaccess and everything seems to be right.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

I have NOT modified the code for app_dev.php neither app.php, everything is just "as is" out of the box.

---

2012-05-02 EDIT

Something weird happened. I edited my config_prod.yml with these lines:

```
# load the profiler
framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

# enable the web profiler
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true
    verbose: true
```

Saved, and then edited the app.php file. Wanted to test what happened if I changed:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); //Symfony default
```

To

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

When I went to app.php/WHATEVER, an error page appeared, so I reverted all changes, restarted Apache and now the WebDebug Toolbar is not showing anymore in PROD (app.php/WHATEVER)

So, I don't know how, but it seems to work as expected now, although the config_prod.yml file and the app.php are in the original state. It also allows me to connect with my external IP to app.php

REALLY weird...

Comment: Which environment are you telling your application to use in the configuration?

Comment: Did you change your apache configuration?

Comment: Nanocom No, I did not change my Apache config. It is the Wamp2.2 default one.

@MetalFrog I did not change any configuration files (config.yml, config_dev.yml, config_prod.yml). Do I have to set something? I thought there was no need to do so!

Comment: Do you still have the "out of the box" .htaccess installed?

Comment: Do you have installed somthing like a php cache or accelerator?

Comment: the same problem comes for me too.. but the debug bar appears in acme bundle not in the newly created one...

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon are you rendering a valid HTML page? The web debug toolbar will only attach itself when there is a body tag in the rendered output.

Comment: yes.. i am rendering a valid html page..

Comment: hey... its working... thanks @michaelotoole  actually you were right web debug bar will only attach when there is a body tag in the rendered output...

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer for those who use the malformed template for output.

*[Link removed for redirecting to spam website]*

Just copied for you:

"Hi. You have to have proper HTML on the page you are viewing. I think the debug bar attaches itself just before the `</body>`. So if you have a page like this (see below) you should see the debug bar."

Code:

```
<html> <head>

</head> <body>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: links are not answers

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable ip filtering in app_dev.php. And you will be able to see the debug bar from external ip.

Regards,
Max